# writing first coffeescript bookmarklets

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, org-mode

I am writing my first bookmarklets in CoffeeScript, but I am having trouble getting anything non-trivial to work.

Here is my desired script, which I want to use to update an org-mode file with a selected snippet from a webpage:

```
fs = require 'fs'

appendfile = fs.createWriteStream('webjournals.org',
    flags: "a"
)
appendfile.write("\n")
appendfile.write("* ")
appendfile.write(document.title)
appendfile.write("\n")
appendfile.end(window.getSelection().toString())
```

This, when compiled to JS (and run through a [bookmarklet-izer](http://subsimple.com/bookmarklets/jsbuilder.htm), does not work. In fact, not even this works:

```
(function() {
  var fs;

  fs = require('fs');

  alert(document.title);

}).call(this);
```

This works, though:

```
(function() {
  var fs;

  alert(document.title);

}).call(this);
```

I manually checked this code up to the browser-related functions in the Coffee interpreter, and it works--I can see the changes in the org-file. What am I missing?

Comment: `require` and fs are features of node.js. A browser such as Firefox doesn't implement them

Comment: Are there any file handling functions in JS?

Comment: help me help you: what do you want to do with the file after you paste the selection?

Comment: ok I found out what org-mode is

Comment: I just want to build up a bookmarklet that is like a poor man's Instapaper, by adding text (and later formatted/linked text) to a minimally formatted text file, which is really all org files are.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to simply use `org-capture` and set up a template to auto-insert the content?

Comment: I would like it to be something portable I can just stick in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `fs` module directly from the browser since it's a node.js API.

The easiest solution I could come out with is for you to [create a web server](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/synopsis.html) with coffeescript (say on localhost:1234) and have the bookmarklet submit a snippet to your server (with [jQuery.post](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.post)), which in turn will write to the local file.

In an illustrative way, a snippet will go from left to right:

Web page --> Bookmarklet --> Local HTTP server --> Org-mode file --> Emacs

Another solution is for you to make a Firefox addon which will have access to your local filesystem (but the [API](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/io/file.html) doesn't seem to allow appending to a file).

There are some new APIs such as the [Filesystem API](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/filesystem) but they seem to be a dead-end as you can't access the full file system but rather a sandboxed one, which you can't access from emacs either.

Comment: It looks like the old mozilla API allowed file appending, but I'm going to give the node.js local server option a try and see how compact a setup it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you're considering using a local web server to run node.js to allow the script to run and access your filesystem (As suggested in guillaume's answer) you should also consider using [Org-Protocol](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-protocol.html) and using a tried and tested method of writing to Org Files ([Org-Capture](http://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html)).

The Org-Protocol tutorial provides the appropriate information for setting up the connection (registry entries for Windows, configuring Emacs.app for Mac and methods for Gnome and KDE), as well as the javascript that will allow the bookmarklet to do the work.

Then you simply need to create an appropriate Capture template to contain the information you've retrieved and format it as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info! For learning's sake I will try it with node.js, and then go back to sensible emacs stuff.